# What's the difference between @RouteConfig and @Routes

Tags: angular, configuration, routes, router

In the documentation of [Angular2 Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), **Configuration** section says

> A router has no route definitions until we configure it. The preferred way to simultaneously create a router and add its routes is with a @RouteConfig decorator applied to the router's host component.

but in the example that follows it's using the `@Routes` decorator instead of `@RouteConfig` and in many examples i have seen use the `@RouteConfig` and that confuses me because i'm not sure how this works...

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent},
    {path: '/heroes',        component: HeroListComponent},
    {path: '/hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent}
])
```

*Note: I'm trying to use the release candidate version of angular2*

---

**Update**

I managed to write an example and make it work using the new decorator `@Routes`.

Plnkr Preview: [Angular2 + Routing + Typescript + materialize-css](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/d7hAuYHOtbNCnZKHTjX2/)

Plnker Code: [Angular2 + Routing + Typescript + materialize-css](http://plnkr.co/edit/d7hAuYHOtbNCnZKHTjX2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular team released RC1 with a totally new routing system. In beta versions of Angular2, routing was configured using `@RouteConfig`. In RC.1, this has been changed to `@Routes`. You can access the beta router by importing from `@angular/router-deprecated` instead of `@angular/router`

Comment: do you have any example? Thanks

Comment: There's an example using `@angular/router-deprecated` in the routing tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html. Depending on your project, there may be some imports that don't resolve by switching to `router-deprecated`. If so, search the `@angular` folder in `node_modules` for the missing class. Migrating from beta to RC.1 was very much a trial and error process.